# __NSCFString setHidden: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios5, hidden, nscfstring

I have got some UILabels which have been declared as property and synthesized. I am hiding those labels in `viewDidLoad`. After some calculations, when I try to unhide them using `hidden` property, app crashes with error mentioned in the subject. I tried `NSLog` to know if it has been deallocated or not, but it is showing me fine values of labels. Please can someone help me that where is memory management problem while I am accessing it normally. Thanks.

Showing some code for reference:

In .h file:

```cs
@interface abc : UIViewController{
   UILabel *value;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *value;
```

In .m file:

```cs
@synthesize value;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
value.hidden = YES;
}

-(IBAction) calculate:(id)sender

//On some button click, assign some value to label and unhide it

NSLog(@"%@",value); //perfectly OK
value.hidden = NO; //throws exception here

}
```

Comment: The error is because the label is getting released. How are you setting value to the label? Can you add that as well? Also add the NSLog statement which is printed in console.

Comment: Oh thank you @ACB you pointed out in right direction. In calculation method, I was assigning text to value rather than its text property. I was writing:  `value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f kcal", (cal / gram) * [amount.text floatValue]];` which is changing reference. Thanks for help :)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Let me add it as an answer. Please accept. :)

Comment: @iAnum now I am facing similar problem. How can I resolve this please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the label is getting released and getting assigned to `NSString`. Check how are you setting value to the label. You should be assigning an `NSString` to `UILabel` which causes it to throw this error when hidden property is called on `value` param.

Comment: You haven't mention what we should do when facing similar problem. How can I assign String to UILabel and hide and unhide it